# Change the innerHTML of EVERY element with specified id

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I am trying to change the innerHTML value of **every** element with id 'filename', but only the first one gets updated.

My problem is that **only the first** element with id 'filename' is updated.

HTML code is generated as a liquid template, but I don't think it should change anything.

Here is the HTML:

```
  <ul>
    {% for product in products %}
      <li>
      <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
      {% for image in product.images %}
        <img src={{ image.src }} height="200px" />
        <p>1) Is your image name descriptive? {{ image.src }}</p>
        <p>2) Is your alt tag descriptive enough? {{ product.title }}</p>
        <p>3) Is your image file type JPEG? <div id="filename">{{ image.src }}</div></p>
      {% endfor %}
      </li>
      <hr>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#filename").each(function()  {
    $(this).html("ext!");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[ID's need to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)** - you should try replacing all elements with `id="filename"` to `class="filename"` instead, and then replacing `#filename` with `.filename` in your `each()` function, so it resembles the following:

```
$(".filename").each(function()  {
    $(this).html("ext!");
});
```

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks! (besides the ext, which wasn't a typo and stands for extension, lol)